# 'If' instruction inside List.ForEach()

Tags: c#, .net, list, foreach

I know that there are many questions about an "if" in lambda statements at SO. Sorry if it's duplication, but i really can't find an answer.

I have this code, and it works well

```
    foreach (Pair<Myclass, int> A in myList) //mylist is List<Pair<Myclass, int>>
        if (A.second <= _width)
            verified.Add(A);
```

Is it possible replace this with `myList.ForEach()` ?

I have tried:

```
myList.ForEach(A => if (A.second < _width) verified.Add(A));
```

and

```
myList.ForEach(A => f.second < _width ? verified.Add(A):do_nothing());
```

But it does not work. Each time when I try to add an 'if' somethings go wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Use [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) instead:

```
var verified = myList.Where(item => item.second <= _width).ToList();
```

Comment: You can use [`FindAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx) instead of LINQ.

Comment: Looks nice, but compiler say that my `List<Pair<Myclass, int>>` haven't `Where`  method

Comment: If verified already exists (and is a List<T>)then it is probably better to use `verified.AddRange(myList.Where(item => item.second <= _width))` to preserve existing elements

Comment: @StepanLoginov add `using System.Linq` to the top of your file and the Where method will be imported (it's something known as an extension method)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
myList.ForEach(A => { if (A.second < _width) verified.Add(A); });
```

You need the curly braces for anything more than a single statement.